# Prevent filter for affecting scorecard - Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

Trying to figure out how to prevent a filter in datastudio prevent changes in my scorecard. Anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [group the filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144?hl=en#what-charts-will-the-filter-control-affect) with only the charts that it is supposed to filter.